# Split String on the Basis of string having character as well as special character

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, split

I want to split my String which I am getting in format::

```
  string filter="  Status~contains~''~and~DossierID~eq~40950~and~CustomerName~eq~'temp'"
```

I want to split it with `("~and~")`

I am doing something like ::

```
var test=filter.Split("~and~");
```

But getting Exception.

Comment: The more you use `ASAP` the less I want to help.

Comment: Are you getting an exception or a compiler error? Please be sure to include enough detail to allow us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting an exception; this won't even compile.

The `.Split()` method doesn't accept a string, only an array of strings.

Try this instead:

```
var test = filter.Split(new[] {"~and~"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

You should get a list of three strings back:

```
  Status~contains~''
DossierID~eq~40950
CustomerName~eq~'temp'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string filter = "  Status~contains~''~and~DossierID~eq~40950~and~CustomerName~eq~'temp'";
string[] tokens = Regex.Split(filter, "~and~");

foreach (string token in tokens)
{
    //Do stuff with token here
}
```

Bear in mind that you need to import System.Text.RegularExpressions in order to use Regex. You could use the string method to split, but I prefer the Regex one, since it takes a string insted of a char[].